# Pandas load text file error: CParserError: Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas, text-files, parse-error

Pandas load text file error: CParserError: Error tokenizing data.

I'm a new pandas learner. I'm trying to use pandas to open a text file. I write code in python, then access to the right path and run the python file, but failed.

Here is the original data. There's no field name, all the rows of data are separated with space:

```
2017-07-02 23:59:51127.0.0.1 GET /ecvv_product/EcvvSearchProduct.aspx cid=202104&p=&pageindex=&kw=electric-skateboard 8082 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;+DigExt;+DTS+Agent - 200 0 0 986 31.7.188.55
2017-07-02 23:59:51 127.0.0.1 GET /ecvv_product/EcvvHotSearchProduct.aspx kw=hydrogen-motor 8082 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;+DigExt;+DTS+Agent - 200 0 0 2539 31.7.188.55
2017-07-02 23:59:51 127.0.0.1 GET /ecvv_product/EcvvSearchProduct.aspx cid=100005713&p=&pageindex=&kw=electric-skateboard 8082 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;+DigExt;+DTS+Agent - 200 0 0 1172 31.7.188.55
2017-07-02 23:59:51 127.0.0.1 GET /ecvv_product/EcvvHotSearchProduct.aspx kw=stainless-stand 8082 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;+DigExt;+DTS+Agent - 200 0 0 3152 31.7.188.55
```

Here is my simple python code:

```
import pandas as pd

DATA_FILE='data.log'
df = pd.read_table(DATA_FILE, sep=" ")

print(df)
```

But I got error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "open.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = pd.read_table(DATA_FILE, sep=" ")
  File "C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()
  File "C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1508, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:10415)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:10691)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 924, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:11437)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 911, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:11308)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 2024, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:27037)
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 4, saw 17
```

There must be something run with my python code. How to get the correct syntax code?

Comment: It does seem like some of the lines in your log file (not the ones you posed) are poorly structured.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a space on the first line:

```
2017-07-02 23:59:51127.0.0.1
```

Replace to:

```
2017-07-02 23:59:51 127.0.0.1
```

Just tested:

```
In [12]: cat data.log
2017-07-02 23:59:51 127.0.0.1 GET /ecvv_product/EcvvSearchProduct.aspx cid=202104&p=&pageindex=&kw=electric-skateboard 8082 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;+DigExt;+DTS+Agent - 200 0 0 986 31.7.188.55
2017-07-02 23:59:51 127.0.0.1 GET /ecvv_product/EcvvHotSearchProduct.aspx kw=hydrogen-motor 8082 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;+DigExt;+DTS+Agent - 200 0 0 2539 31.7.188.55
2017-07-02 23:59:51 127.0.0.1 GET /ecvv_product/EcvvSearchProduct.aspx cid=100005713&p=&pageindex=&kw=electric-skateboard 8082 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;+DigExt;+DTS+Agent - 200 0 0 1172 31.7.188.55
2017-07-02 23:59:51 127.0.0.1 GET /ecvv_product/EcvvHotSearchProduct.aspx kw=stainless-stand 8082 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;+DigExt;+DTS+Agent - 200 0 0 3152 31.7.188.55

In [13]: dx = pd.read_table('data.log', sep=" ", header=None)

In [14]: dx
Out[14]: 
           0         1          2    3   \
0  2017-07-02  23:59:51  127.0.0.1  GET   
1  2017-07-02  23:59:51  127.0.0.1  GET   
2  2017-07-02  23:59:51  127.0.0.1  GET   
3  2017-07-02  23:59:51  127.0.0.1  GET   

                                        4   \
0     /ecvv_product/EcvvSearchProduct.aspx   
1  /ecvv_product/EcvvHotSearchProduct.aspx   
2     /ecvv_product/EcvvSearchProduct.aspx   
3  /ecvv_product/EcvvHotSearchProduct.aspx   

                                                  5     6  7          8   \
0    cid=202104&p=&pageindex=&kw=electric-skateboard  8082  -  127.0.0.1   
1                                  kw=hydrogen-motor  8082  -  127.0.0.1   
2  cid=100005713&p=&pageindex=&kw=electric-skateb...  8082  -  127.0.0.1   
3                                 kw=stainless-stand  8082  -  127.0.0.1   

                                                  9  10   11  12  13    14  \
0  Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;...  -  200   0   0   986   
1  Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;...  -  200   0   0  2539   
2  Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;...  -  200   0   0  1172   
3  Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.0;+Windows+NT;...  -  200   0   0  3152   

            15  
0  31.7.188.55  
1  31.7.188.55  
2  31.7.188.55  
3  31.7.188.55
```

Comment: It works! But for original data file which is almost 193MB, the same error happens again. Does it means the original data file got something invalid?

Comment: Use warn_bad_lines=True. If error_bad_lines is False, and warn_bad_lines is True, a warning for each “bad line” will be output. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table

Comment: After I add all the reference to get rid of the possible error (I used skiprows=None, skipfooter=None, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True), it still get the same error. Anyway, I'm stilling struggling to find the invalid error from original data...lol